# Importing properties from other Yaml in application.yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot

In a spring boot 3 application, I want to define within the application.yml a properties list. Each element of this list should be imported from another yml file. After trying different possibilities, I haven't been unable to achieve this goal

This is my approach:

**provider1.yml**

```yaml
provider1:
  name: MyProvider
  priority: 2
```

**application.yml**

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - classpath:providers/provider1.yml
      - classpath:providers/provider2.yml

providers:
  list:
    - ${provider1}
    - ${provider2}
```

**ProviderProperties.java**

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "providers")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class ProviderProperties {
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public static class ProviderConfig {
        private Map<Integer, List<String>> discriminator;
        private String token;
        private String byField;
        private List<String> serviceIds;
        private int priority;
        private String name;
        private int prefixLength;
    }
    private List<ProviderConfig> list;
}
```

When running the project I have the following error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'providers.list[0]' to my.package.ProviderProperties$ProviderConfig:

    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [my.package.ProviderProperties$ProviderConfig]
```

But if I have any of the following application.yml, th application runs OK:

**application.yml (this works fine)**

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - classpath:providers/agm.yml

providers:
  list:
    - name: ${provider1.name}
      priority: ${provider1.priority}
    - name: ${provider2.name}
      priority: ${provider2.priority}
```

Any idea to make it work with the first approach??

Comment: Use something like `items` , see this https://golangnow.com/posts/convert-tradition-kubernetes-yaml-to-list/ (my blog), let's share with me result. Other direction: need `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:foo.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)` see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource#propertysource-and-yaml-in-action

Comment: Thanks. This approach works fine, but I need that those properties being loaded automatically, without specifying the files in @PropertySource.